# Javascript function not being called in "fiddle"

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I made this short fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NZnN2/. Why is it not popping up the alert when I click the button?

Comment: As @Rocket pointed out, you must set 'no wrap' instead of 'onload' in the left bar.

Comment: I'm lost.  Why is this question being voted down so aggressively?  It could be improved a bit by explaining a bit more about what the issue is exactly, but s/he's got a fiddle that is easy to use and see the problem...?

Comment: No code in the question, no explanation of what is / isn't happening, terrible title.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because your JavaScript code is in an `onload` handler, which means `display_message` is not global, and therefore not accessible by the HTML.

Since you selected `onLoad`, your JavaScript is injected into the page like this:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    function display_message(){
        alert("woohoo!");
    }
});
```

As you can see, `display_message` is only accessible inside that anonymous function.  To make the example work, change `onLoad` to `no wrap (head)` or `no wrap (body)` (on the left side of the page).

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NZnN2/8/

Comment: In other words: it's a scope issue

Comment: ...and therefore, you need to change the dropdown on the side.

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
function display_message() {
    alert('woohoo!');
}
```

do

```
display_message = function () {
    alert('woohoo!');
}
```

Comment: which browser do you use? (on google chrome, this is working)

Comment: @BenniKa: Not really. It will make the variable global, and therefore accessible to the inline handler.

Comment: @BenniKa: Not quite.  Without `var` in front of `display_message =`, it'll make it a global variable.

Comment: Or better yet, `window.display_message =`.